# Firebase realtime freezes UI android java

Tags: android, firebase, user-interface

I have a few years android/Firebase experience . I ve seen several mentions of firebase actions not being able to freeze the UI while in fact me and other people have experienced it and I never saw any proper solution . Back thread doesn t help .
Writing on an already quite populated node (non populated node doesnt freeze)

This example is built in purpose to underline the fact that "firebase writes in Bg" , hence no action on the UI doesn t apply here

GC is called in the traces and UI Freezes . If not using any specific drawable , UI doesn t freeze (if no other action taken on the UI, if any GC called and app freezes)

```
Handler handlerGlow = new Handler();
Runnable   glowRunnable = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        new Thread(() -> {
            Random random = new Random();

                   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("AAA").setValue(random.nextBoolean());

        }).start();



        handlerGlow.postDelayed(this, 300);
    }
};

glowRunnable.run();
```

To make the UI freeze :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Define the background properties like color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#000001"
                android:centerColor="#0b131e"
                android:centerY="1.0"
                android:endColor="#0d1522"
                android:angle="270"
                />
        </shape>
    </item>

    <!-- Define the progress properties like start color, end color etc -->
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape>
                <gradient
                    android:startColor="#007A00"
                    android:centerColor="#007A00"
                    android:centerY="1.0"
                    android:endColor="#06101d"
                    android:angle="270"
                    />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and in the activity :

```
  <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:minHeight="500dp"
        android:minWidth="500dp"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/aaa"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```